# Join with all nature in manifold witness

Tags: meaning, lyrics

In the song *Great is Thy faithfulness* there is a line that reads

> Join with all nature in manifold witness

What does that mean? What is *manifold witness*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["Manifold"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/manifold) has the meaning of :

> having many different forms, features, or elements:

The fact that the "sun, moon, and stars", are joining the whole of nature as a witness(like in a court)of God's great faithfulness, mercy, and love.   Because it is the "whole of nature", this witness is bound to be composed of "many different elements".

Answer (score 0):

The hymn writer was expressing the idea that the Bible conveys in Psalm 19:1,

> The heavens declare the glory of God; And the firmament shows His handiwork.

(See also the Apostle Paul’s application of this idea in Romans 1:18-32.)

The created world bears witness to the evidence of a Creator! Some people can’t find God for the same reason that a criminal can’t find a police man! They don’t want to!