# What do you call an "ox" with all his parts

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

In a crossword game, a dictionary defined "ox" as a castrated male of the genus *Bos*.  What's the word for one uncastrated (and for a female)?

Same dictionary says it "oxen" is the "only survivor … of the old English weak plural."  Is "children" a fake survivor?

Comment: And how in the world did the dupe finder suggest https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40516/join-with-all-nature-in-manifold-witness as a possible duplicate?!?

Comment: The automated duplicate finder is not intelligent. "With all" is common to both titles, and I guess that's enough.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewLeach — I missed that.  The dupe finder is definitely not intelligent.  It almost never suggests a duplicate for me, but after I post, there are often duplicates in the "related" sidebar.

Comment: I would buy a new dictionary, that one is obviously broken.

Comment: [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ox) gives a more realistic treatment, with the 'castrated' caveat only applicable to one sense. A typical example of the polysemy-with-hyponymy problem not uncommon in English.

Comment: The dictionary is built into the game which is free.

Comment: Your second question is answered [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/180564/191178).

Answer (score 4):

The male is a *[bull](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bull)* and the female is a *[cow](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cow)*. *[Cattle](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cattle)*, used as the plural, refers to both male and female.